# Gems to assist in monitoring code quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am looking to really ratchet down on my code quality as a start a new project. I think I'm prone to many mistakes in the areas of code test coverage, adherence to ruby/rails conventions and security.

I've come across gems like [Rubocop](http://batsov.com/rubocop/) and the awesome [Refactor Cop](http://www.refactorcop.com/) which return information about convention violations and other warnings.

I've also been using the [guard gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard) to monitor changes in my code against my tests.

I've also seen [codeclimate](https://codeclimate.com) but can't yet commit resources to it.

Which gems are recommended for producing digests of what code (I'm less interested in rails/gems/libraries) isn't yet under sensible test coverage? Also slightly broader - are there any other well respected gems/projects that might help boost my code quality.

Or perhaps even more broadly - what are good questions to be asking yourself while  reviewing if your code is of sufficient quality/security (might help me target a search for tools in future)!

Comment: Also, for the record I am using git!

Comment: Look at [rubycritic](https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic) for code quality report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following myself. I've found `rubycritic` particularly useful, and I believe it is the gem underlying a lot of the Code Climate reviews.

The `sandi_meter` is one I haven't used as much, but strongly encourages smaller methods.

I also strongly encourage using `simplecov` to help you evaluate your code coverage. Code coverage is by no means a panacea for any code problem, but it'll at least ensure that you do not miss segments of your code altogether.

The full list:

```
  gem 'traceroute' # Checks for undefined routes and unreachable actions.
  gem 'bullet' # Checks for query optimizations.
  gem 'rails_best_practices' # Checks for code optimization.
  gem 'rubycritic' # Checks for code optimization.
  gem 'sandi_meter' # Checks for compliance to Sandi Metz's rules for developers.
  gem 'simplecov' #Enables coverage analysis of code.
```

Comment: I can confirm I've now begun using all of these - which combine to give me fantastic reporting to suggest where I could improve the quality of my code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of questions in here, I'll do my best to address each one.

> Which gems are recommended for producing digests of what code (I'm less interested in rails/gems/libraries) isn't yet under sensible test coverage?

If you are looking to simply measure test coverage `simplecov` is your best option.

> Also slightly broader - are there any other well respected gems/projects that might help boost my code quality.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29036712/1209435) has a great list of other gems that can help automate code quality checking.  I would add Thoughtbot's [HoundCI project](https://houndci.com/) as another tool - it adds comments to your code once you push it up to GitHub... sorta like a robot code review.  It's free for open source projects.

> Or perhaps even more broadly - what are good questions to be asking yourself while reviewing if your code is of sufficient quality/security (might help me target a search for tools in future)!

We're entering into subjective territory here, but I would encourage you to be pragmatic about striving for an A from Code Climate or 100% test coverage.  For example, if you work for NASA perhaps 100% test coverage makes sense... but on your web app, striving for 100% test coverage can lead to writing a lot of tests for code that you don't own (such as a Gem or Rails itself).  I would encourage you to look at Jay Fields' [Working Effectively with Unit Tests](https://leanpub.com/wewut) for a more nuanced (and seasoned) opinion here.

Ultimately, you should strive to write code that is *easy to maintain and change*.  Bob Martin's books and talks are a great resource, which you can find on [his site](https://cleancoders.com/).

Comment: Thoughtbot again! I just installed bourbon and neat :) they're rapidly becoming my entire stack!

Many thanks for this comprehensive answer - and for patience with my final venture into subjective territory.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the [awesome ruby list](http://awesome-ruby.com/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) which has all sorts of great gems but particulary a good section on code analysis and metrics, they suggest:

**CODE ANALYSIS AND METRICS**

```
gem 'Barkeep' # Barkeep is a fast, fun way to review code. Engineering organizations can use it to keep the bar high.
gem 'Brakeman' # A static analysis security vulnerability scanner for Ruby on Rails applications.
gem 'Cane' # Code quality threshold checking as part of your build.
gem 'Coverband' # Rack middleware to help measure production code coverage.
gem 'Flay' # Flay analyzes code for structural similarities. Differences in literal values, variable, class, method names, whitespace, programming style, braces vs do/end, etc are all ignored. Making this totally rad.
gem 'Flog' # Flog reports the most tortured code in an easy to read pain report. The higher the score, the more pain the code is in.
gem 'fukuzatsu' # Complexity analysis tool with a rich web fron't# nd.
gem 'MetricFu' # A fist full of code metrics.
gem 'Pronto' # Quick automated code review of your changes.
gem 'rails_best_practices' # A code metric tool for rails projects.
gem 'Reek' # Code smell detector for Ruby.
gem 'Rubocop' # A static code analyzer, based on the community Ruby style guide.
gem 'Rubycritic' # A Ruby code quality reporter.
gem 'SimpleCov' # Code coverage for Ruby 1.9+ with a powerful configuration library and automatic merging of coverage across test suites.
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you are feeling "*adventurous*", try swapping general code coverage reporting (e.g.`simplecov`) with [mutation testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) libraries such as [Mutant](https://github.com/mbj/mutant).

> Wikipedia: Mutation testing (or Mutation analysis or Program mutation) is used to design new software tests and evaluate the quality of existing software tests. Mutation testing involves modifying a program in small ways.

- [Here is a pretty good breakdown](https://troessner.svbtle.com/kill-all-the-mutants-a-deep-dive-into-mutation-testing-and-how-the-mutant-gem-works) of what Mutant Gem does and how it tests the quality of your specs.
- [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WccaOMuf01Y&t=2131s) is Sferik's talk from RaislConf2014, on why Mutant is much more efficient than SimpleCov.

I say "adventurous" because I found it nearly impossible to get a 100% coverage ( i.e. 'kill' all mutations).

Comment: This sounds super interesting!! Thank you for the suggestion!